# A question about Analysis operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Define $T: H \rightarrow \ell^{2} \text { be the analysis operator } T x=\left\{\left\langle x, e_{n}\right\rangle\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, I would like to find $\text {  explicit formulas for } T^{*} T \text { and } T T^{*}$. I have shown that $T$  is a surjective linear isometry, thus it is a unitary operator. Is that enough to claim that $T^*T$ and $TT^*$are identity operator? If not, what additional conditions may needed? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $TT^{*}$  is the identity on $\ell^{2}$ and $T^{*}T$ is the identity on $H$.

Answer (score 0):

A surjective isometry is an unitary. From $T$ being an isometry, you get $$\langle T^*Tx,x\rangle =\langle Tx,Tx\rangle=\|Tx\|^2=\|x\|^2=\langle x,x\rangle.$$ Then polarization gives you $T^*T=I$. As $T$ is surjective, $$\ker TT^*=\ker T^*=\operatorname{ran}(T)^\perp={0}.$$Combined with $(TT^*)^2=TT^*TT^*=TT^*$, we get that $TT^*$ is an injective projection, so $TT^*=I$.

Comment: I was thinking the same. Actually this question is from homework question: $\begin{array}{l}\text { (b) Find explicit formulas for } T^{*} T \text { and } T T^{*} \\ \text { (c) When will } T^{*} T \text { be the identity operator? }\end{array}$.I have shown in (b) that $T^{*} T \text { and } T T^{*}$ are identity so I'm curious why there is (c).

Comment: If $H$ is infinite-dimensional and separable, then $T$ is a unitary. Maybe the exercise allows $\dim H<\infty$?

Comment: If $\{e_n\}$ is not basis, just oethononrmal sequence for $H$, then $T$ is not surjective. Is $TT^*$ still identity?

Comment: No, if $T$ is an isometry but not surjective, then $TT^*$ is the orthogonal projection onto the range of $T$.

Comment: Could you please give a hint on how to show that?

Comment: I was thinking since $\left(T T^{*}\right)^{2}=T T^{*} T T^{*}=T T^{*}$ still holds, $TT^*$ is still $I$?

Comment: If $T$ is not surjective, then $TT^*=I$ is impossible. The equality $X^2=X$ ok only tells you that $X$ is a projection.